# Query not fetching all the records

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a xml structure:

```
 <pit>
  <ROW TestID="47855" ExecutionID="1510034507" TestName="USHP" AssertionName="Check News" Status="1" TestLatencyMs="5448" Date="2011-11-29 01:43:45.117" HttpCode="" Error="" TestOwner="mdk" AssertionID="119117" /> 
  <ROW TestID="47855" ExecutionID="1510028579" TestName="USHP" AssertionName="Check News" Status="0" TestLatencyMs="7312" Date="2011-11-29 01:41:46.273" HttpCode="" Error="" TestOwner="fdxk" AssertionID="119117" /> 
  <ROW TestID="47855" ExecutionID="1510022153" TestName="USHP" AssertionName="Check News" Status="0" TestLatencyMs="5860" Date="2011-11-29 01:39:44.153" HttpCode="" Error="" TestOwner="klo" AssertionID="119117" /> 
  </pit>
```

and I am trying to use this query to fetch my ExecutionIDs but to no avail :( I don't know what is wrong.

```
    List<int> executionIdList = new List<int>();
    try
    {
        executionIdList = (from result in xDoc.Root.Descendants("ROW")
                            where result != null &&
                            result.Attribute("Status").Value.Equals("0", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

                           select result.Attributes("ExecutionID")).FirstOrDefault().Select(x => int.Parse( x.Value)).ToList();
    }
```

I get only the first value with the above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch yout ExecutionIds from the XDocument as shown below:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Sample1.xml");
List<string> ids = doc.Descendants("pit").Elements().Select(i => i.Attribute("ExecutionID").Value).ToList();
```

The above code loads the xml from the file Sample1.xml and then fetches all the executionIDs into a list object. You can add more conditions to the query if needed like you are checking if the status value is "0". Below is the code with the condition

```
List<string> ids = doc.Descendants("pit").Elements().Where(k=>k.Attribute("Status").Value == "0").Select(i => i.Attribute("ExecutionID").Value).ToList();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are not getting the results is because

```
IEnumerable<int> executionIds;

executionIds =
    from result in xDoc.Root.Descendants("ROW").Attributes("ExecutionID")
    select int.Parse(result.Value);
```

Is what you need. Your function includes a lot of seemingly unnecessary code (but that is for you to judge) in the select portion, including a FirstorDefault statement which will only select the first record or default to a predefined value if no record exists.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting elements of first row because your query is calling descendants on "ROW" element i.e.

> xDoc.Root.Descendants("ROW")

Try by replacing this with following code :

> xDoc.Root.Descendants("pit")

This will return all the  elements, which are the descendants of  element.

Comment: nope this doesnt work..I get a object reference exception with this

Comment: He can select "ROW" and it will return a collection of all "ROW" elements. "Pit" would return the parent element which you would have to iterate through afterwards unnecessarily.

Comment: I think I got this

            executionIdList = (from result in xDoc.Root.Descendants("ROW")
                               where result != null &&
                               result.Attribute("Status").Value.Equals("Fail", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

                               select int.Parse( result.Attribute("ExecutionID").Value)).ToList();